# How to Restore Tables in a Database from csv files in PgAdmin (PostgreSQL)

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4, macos-mojave, postgresql-14

I am trying to restore a database using PgAdmin on a Mac but the tables do not get imported. Tables came in csv format and compressed in a zipped file but I made it into a tar file because PgAdmin only accepts tar format but I still don't get the tables.

I changed the tables from CSV to excel workbook (xlxs) format and compressed them into a tar file again but this doesn't work. I reinstalled the program and used an old file I used before (also a tar file, inner files are in dac format). The tables in this (old) file get restored so I know it's not my system. I have tried restoring the database by going the directory route and using the unzipped folder but the tables still don't come up. I then tried creating the tables on PgAmin and importing the data from the CSV file, does not work either. I am not sure what else to do.